# Website not available everywhere

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, availability

Today I noticed my website http://mint-nachhilfe.ch/ was down, but other people (located in different networks) said it looks up from there. When I came home, I double-checked, and I can really reach it from here. Also, [this website](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/mint-nachhilfe.ch) considers it down.

Some facts:

- It's a Tomcat webapp, connected to an Apache2 server. I restarted both, no change.
- Another (ruby on rails) application is connected to this Apache2, which I couldn't reach either, but is considered online by above check website.
- At any point, I could directly connect to the Tomcat over http://mint-nachhilfe.ch:8080!

I don't know how to go on searching for the root error. I assume it's related to the Apache2 server, but how could that be?

**Update:**

It is reachable directly by the IP `178.77.103.22` I got from an `nslookup` triggered inside the problematic network. The problem seems to be related to Apache's domain distinction. My VirutualHost entry looks as follows (there are few others as well):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mint-nachhilfe.ch
    ServerAlias mint-nachhilfe.ch *.mint-nachhilfe.ch

    JkMount /* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: http://ping.ms/#mint-nachhilfe.ch says the server is reachable from just about everywhere. Must be Apache if you're still seeing issues. Anything in Apache's error logs about denied requests or whatever?

Comment: What does your apache httpd.conf file say?  Are there any deny from's in there?

Comment: My `httpd.conf` is empty. The error log says a lot of things I don't completely understand (I'm no server expert). In the time when I tried to access it, there's only one entry: `server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting`. Not sure what this means exactly. Also, the problem persisted after a restart.

Comment: Wouldn't the error you're getting suggest that you edit the Tomcat configuration and change the `MaxClients` setting?  What OS are you running your Apache/Tomcat on?

Comment: @ChrisS: I could always successfully ping the server, even ssh worked flawlessly.

Comment: @Deesbek: The server is running on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: (updated the question)

Answer (score 0):

Look for and edit the `MaxClients` in your Tomcat configuration.

Restart your Tomcat server.

Comment: There were 3 entries of `MaxClients`. I increased them from 40 to 80. Nothing changed.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach Did you restart both Tomcat and Apache after the change? I am sure you did but just thought I would ask.

Comment: Had restarted Apache, and now did the same for Tomcat, just to be sure. Nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe DNS issues.  Can you access it internally via IP? If you can then it is a DNS issue.

Comment: Yes, I can (just updated my question). But I can also reach it through `domain:8080`, which is directly served by Tomcat. Also, `nslookup` returns the correct IP.

Comment: can you try internally using: `http://www.mint-nachhilfe.ch/`

Comment: Sorry for the spam but I would compare your apache entry to the Tomcat one for `http://mint-nachhilfe.ch:8080`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11109/discussion-between-cedric-reichenbach-and-deesbek)